# Apache Flume - how to transfer csv files, one-to-one

Tags: csv, flume

The closest I got is that every line of data from source (that are multiple files) is written to just one file on the sink side. I use "spooldir" on source side, and "file_roll" on sink side. How can I improve this to copy files one-to-one, with the same file name?

Comment: What do you mean by "one to one"?

Comment: I basically want to copy file(s) from one computer to another, using Apache Flume, and "file_rool" sink type is the closest I got. But it generates multiple files with weird file names, and I want it to be like on the src side.

Answer (score 0):

You can use spooling directory as http://flume.apache.org/FlumeUserGuide.html#spooling-directory-source and set the roll size to 0 in your conf file as:

```
agent.sinks.hdfsSink.hdfs.rollSize = 0
```

This is what I extract from Flume documentation:

**hdfs.rollSize 1024    File size to trigger roll, in bytes (0: never roll based on file size)**

Answer (score 0):

> You can use BLOB deserializer to transefer complete file as an event. it works fine for small files.
>
> > For example if you have 10000 files of 10kb in your spool directory. it would pick 100 file in one go (as per default batch size of spool dir) and transfer it to HDFS(if you are using a HDFS sink). you can also verify file count in HDFS. Bigger file size could lead to channel full exception or out of memory error.
>
> To implement this you just need to add below property to your flume source conf file -

```
agent-name.sources.spool-dir.deserializer = org.apache.flume.sink.solr.morphline.BlobDeserializer$Builder
```